# Firestore wont retrieve my data when I use where

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from my database using where. The user inputs an email they would like to invite and then an invite is sent. However no document is being returned. This is the code I'm using to retrieve:

```
await props.firestore
    .collection("users")
    .where("email", "==", state.inviteEmail)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        props.showMsg(
          "No user with that email exists. Make sure you've entered it correctly"
        );
      } else {
        // This is where it goes if it works
        alert("It works");
      }
    });
```

I've tried replacing the where with .doc(any id) and it works so I know the database is connected properly. This is the view of the database:

[image: Screenshot of the database]

I'm using Reactjs and the database is using Firebase

EDIT: For anyone else having the same issue, this was the change I made:

```
await props.firestore
    .collection("users")
    .where("email", "==", state.inviteEmail)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.empty) {
        props.showMsg(
          "No user with that email exists. Make sure you've entered it correctly"
        );
      } else {
        alert("This emails username: "+doc.docs[0].data().username);
      }
    });
```

The data is being returned as a QuerySnapshot which is like an array so instead of doc.Data() it needed to be doc.docs[0].data. As I only have one guaranteed returned document I just grabbed the first element, but if I had multiples I would have to use a foreach.

Comment: I only added the word solved to the title as I seen it done on other questions. I also included the solution to my question as I felt it was helpful to explain why I was having the issue in the first place. Whenever I have come across questions on this site, it can be frustrating to have to go through multiple links to figure out how they solve their issue so I felt if I put the solution to mine it may help others in the future more effectively. I was unaware that stack overflow had such rules

Comment: That's OK. That's why I explained both the what and why. For some discussions on this topic that you may find more credible: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question

Comment: Oh I see, I get what you mean. Tbh I didn't realize I could post an answer on my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a `where` clause, you are essentially getting a `QuerySnapshot` object in return instead of a `DocumentSnapshot`. So the problem in your code is that `QuerySnapshot` object does not have an `exists` field as the `DocumentSnapshot` object. Thus `doc.exists` will always be equal to `undefined` in this case and the if statement will always evaluate to true.

You may convert your if condition to look for the `empty` property instead, so the code will look like this:

```
firestore
.collection("users")
.where("email", "==", state.inviteEmail)
.get()
.then((snap) => {
  if (snap.empty) {
    props.showMsg(
      "No user with that email exists. Make sure you've entered it correctly"
    );
  } else {
    // This is where it goes if it works
    alert("It works");
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but I kept getting "doc.data is not a function" meaning it couldn't grab anything. I've replaced the alert saying it worked with props.showMsg("Email's username: " + doc.data().username);

Comment: @Lonstu this is because the `QuerySnapshot` object does not have a `data` function. You are confusing `QuerySnapshot` with the `DocumentSnapshot` object as I mentioned earlier. Try to think of `QuerySnapshot` as a collection of `DocumentSnapshot` with some other properties and methods too like `forEach` for iterating and `size` that holds the number of documents returned. For a better understanding please go through the firestore's [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) on `QuerySnapshot`

Comment: thank you. I didn't realize it was QuerySnapshot that was being returned and that it was being treated like an array. I used doc.docs[0].data().username and it worked. Thank you again!